# Automatic Data Load from Excel 2010 file to SQL Server 2012 table

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I am new to SQL Server and using SQL Server 2012 on Windows 2008.

As my very first job, I have to import an Excel 2010 file located on a remote windows based machine into SQL Server table.

Additional complexity to the task is that user is generating that excel file from another software frequently. Therefore I need to import only the last file generated by user and then move that file to an archive folder after completion of import.

Can you guide me please how to accomplish this job?

Comment: There are already a number of tutorials and guides freely available on the internet.   Your question is too broad.   Try doing some research and attempting a solution, and if you encounter an error at some specific point, come back and ask about that, and show what you have done so far to attempt to solve it.

Comment: I would use SSIS.  Dataflow to load and file task to archive.  There are plenty of examples just search for excel ssis

Comment: This is a multi step process and you have to make sure the SQL Server windows credentials are set to access the remote folder and the proper providers are installed in the server running the import.  One of the standard ways to do this is using SQL Server Data Tools and setting up a SSIS package.

Comment: Dear Tab...yes I've already explored the google and especially this forum, but what I couldn't find (or at least couldn't understand) is how to schedule this import as an ongoing job which should run after every 15 minutes? All of the solutions I've read are just to read a specific file and get that import into Db Table at once and that's all.

Comment: Secondly, in my case, excel files are having a time stamp at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If your user is creating the Excel files at a regular interval, you can use DOS batch files to identify, rename, and archive the created Excel files. An example would be: 
ren C:\SQL\Daily_Billing_Report\Daily_Billing_Report.xlsx Daily_Billing_Report-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%.xlsx

This would add a time stamp to the end of the file name. 
The following could be added to the batch file to execute in conjunction with the previous code to rename and archive the file in one step.

move C:\SQL\Daily_Billing_Report\Daily_Billing_Report-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%.xlsx C:\SQL\SSIS_Packages\Daily_Billing_Report\arch

You would actually call this batch file from an SSIS package that did the actual data extraction from the Excel file to the SQL table.

Since your users are creating files at irregular intervals, I might create a package that will exit normally if there is no file present and process a file if it is present. Schedule package to run every 5 minutes either SQL Agent or with Windows task scheduler.

Comment: Dear Blake, there is no specific time of file generation, a user generates that file whenever he need from a 3rd party system. It may be twice within an hour or only one once a day. Therefore I am planning to execute this import job either to import all files at once and then move them all to archive folder or it should import one latest file at a time. When it will run next time, it will import 2nd most old file and this way all the files one by one. Hope the scenario is clear now and advise me according.